# Figuring out indexes or structure to speed up query -- MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I need help figuring out certain indexes or some different structure to speed up my query, I've tried grouping first and then selected the results from grouped CTEs as per the following...
http://codeidol.com/sql/sql-performance-tuning/GROUP-BY/Optimal-GROUP-BY-Clauses/

I ended up just wiping that however, and the following is the basic query which is taking 2 mins, queries 730,000 records and has a 91% cost on sorting, I'm assuming it is going mostly towards the grouping. I really need this to get down to 1 min at least.

### Query:

```
SELECT
        tblFLS.fldFN,
        tblFLS.fldRN,
        tblFC.fldFC,
        tblFC.fldCity,
        tblFC.fldState,
        tblFLS.fldIN,
        tblUL.fldPRK,
        tblUL.fldLN,
        tblUA.fldANA,
        tblUA.fldMTH,
        (CASE
            WHEN (ISNULL([fldDTT], '') = '') THEN [fldDTT2]
            ELSE [fldDTT]
        END) AS fldDate,
        tblUA.fldPG
    FROM tblUA
    INNER JOIN tblUL ON tblUA.fldULKey = tblUL.fldULID
    INNER JOIN tblFLS ON tblUL.fldFileKey = tblFLS.fldFileID
    INNER JOIN tblFC ON tblFLS.fldFacKey = tblFC.fldFacID
    GROUP BY
        tblFLS.fldFN,
        tblFLS.fldRN,
        tblFC.fldFC,
        tblFC.fldCity,
        tblFC.fldState,
        tblFLS.fldIN,
        tblUL.fldPRK tblUL.fldLN,
        tblUA.fldANA,
        tblUA.fldMTH, 
        (CASE
            WHEN (ISNULL([fldDDT], '') = '') THEN [fldDDT2]
            ELSE [fldDDT]
        END),
        tblUA.fldPG
```

### Table Structure:

```
tblUA -- 850,000 rows, clustered Index on fldUAID

fldULK... INT
fldUAID... INT
fldALY... NVARCHAR(10)
fldAK... INT
fldMTH... NVARCHAR(15)
fldMK... INT
fldMMK... TINYINT
fldUNI... NVARCHAR(10)
fld7... INT
fld8... TINYINT
fld9...TINYINT
fld10...TINYINT

tblUL -- 200,000 rows, clustered Index on fldULID

fldULID... INT
fldFK... INT
fldPRK... INT
fld2... INT
fld3... INT
fldLN... NVARCHAR(15)
fldDTT... DATETIME
fldDTT2... DATETIME

tblFLS -- 70,000 rows, clustered Index on Primary Key, Non-Unique Non-Clustered On: fldDV, fldFK, fldIN, fldMK

    fldFN... NVARCHAR(255)
    fldRN... NVARCHAR(255)
    fldIN... NVARCHAR(100)
    fldDV... NVARCHAR(5)
    fldM... NVARCHAR(100)
    fldMK... INT
    fldINC... NVARCHAR(10)
    fldIDN... NVARCHAR(30)
    fldDTA... NVARCHAR(50)

    tblFC -- 10,000 records, clustered Index on Primary Key, Non-Unique Non-Clustered on fldFCID

    fldFCID... INT
    fldFC..NVARCHAR(100)
    fldADDR... NVARCHAR(50)
    fldADDR2... NVARCHAR(50)
    fldCity... NVARCHAR(50)
    fldState... NVARCHAR(10)
```

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: you should include at least your `table structure` and `indexes on used tables` and a peek at your `execution plan` would be nice also, that way you can receive help without too much guessing, because without this information we only can guess...

Comment: Won't affect performance, but I think `coalesce(nullif(field1, ''), field2)` is more readable than `(CASE WHEN (IsNull([fldDTT], '') = '') THEN [fldDTT2] ELSE [fldDTT] END)`

Comment: I think there is a comma missing in the `group by` in `tblUL.fldPRK tblUL.fldLN`? probably just a copy pasting error since you are asking about performance?

Comment: Just one side note: This may very well be just a matter of personal taste, but using such abbreviations for table names makes for really bad reading (IMHO). First they start all with the same prefix and then just something cryptic follows `tblUA, tblUL, tblFLS, tblFC` => not that easy to distinguish. I would advice to not be afraid of long table names, since when you are trying to optimize performace you will be reading your names a lot ;)

Comment: @tripleddev I think you can almost be helped here :) You should include the scripts for creating your indexes, too; just mentioning that there exist indexes on certain columns is not explicit enough

Comment: That screenshot of the execution plan is too small for my eyes to make sense of. Got it in a larger resolution perhaps?

Comment: @SchmitzIT the resolution is pretty okay actually it is just minimized automatically by SO to fit the page but you can still zoom in with CTRL + mousewheel or open the image in a separate tab ,)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - Thanks! I tried clicking but forgot about opening in a new tab

Comment: SQL Server feels insulted by the bad table and attribute names, so it cripples the server performance

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the query often, then pre-compute the group by section into a helper table

Also, you can simplify the calculation with `ISNULL([fldDDT], [fldDDT2])`